# Incremental load for JIRA Rest API in Qliksense

Tags: api, rest, jira, qlikview, qliksense

How to do Incremental load for JIRA rest API? As the full load consumes a lot of time.
http://localhost:8080/rest/api/3/search
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.15.0/#api/2/search-searchUsingSearchRequest You can provide "startAt" and "maxResults" fields in your JSON

Comment: And are you using Cloud or Server? api/3 looks like a cloud url but localhost looks like server.

Comment: we are using server on premise